# ffmpeg Windows XP Entry Point Not Found Error

Tags: windows-xp, ffmpeg

after downloading ffmpeg I tried to open the .exe file and I receive this error:

[image]

This is using the lastest x32 build from ffmpeg's web site. Is anyone aware of a way to fix this or does this software simply not support XP anymore?

Comment: Download link??

Comment: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ (linked to from ffmpeg.org website). I chose the standard x86 version

Comment: Which build? Static, Shared or Dev?

Comment: Tried both Static and Shared and same problem.

Comment: What I would try is copy msvcrt.dll from a windows 7 PC, put it in the same folder where you execute the ffmpeg installer is, then try the executable again.

Comment: Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft, and [XP support was dropped by Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2937).

Answer (score 4):

here are builds that support windows xp

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegwindowsbi/files/2016-08-12-v3.1.2/

via ffmpeg zeranoe site:

https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=3572
(in that thread you have more sources for other xp-compatible builds on page 4)